# pip freeze lists packages uninstalled through pip, then reinstalled through Pacman

Tags: arch-linux, python, pacman, pip

Because I've heard that it's a very bad idea to install packages through `pip` instead of through a package manager, I'm trying to identify all the packages that I've installed through `pip` that are also readily available in `pacman`'s official repositories. Not all of them are (I understand that I can explore AUR or package them myself, but for right now I'm trying to stay within the official repositories), so I'm leaving some of them installed through `pip` for now, and migrating the rest to `pacman`.

My (admittedly primitive) workflow to do this has been:

1. `pip freeze | less`; choose a package to migrate (essentially arbitrary)
2. `pacman -Ss python-packagename` (If unfound, abort and retry with a different package)
3. `sudo pip uninstall packagename`
4. `sudo pacman -S python-packagename`
5. If `pacman` reports file conflicts, repeat steps 2 through 4 for all dependent packages before reattempting step 5 on the target package.

This works, insofar as I believe I'm successfully now managing the package through `pacman` - `pacman -Ql python-packagename` lists files that appear correct, and anecdotally I've seen packages updated through `pacman` as well, indicating that `pacman` has taken over responsibility for updating the packages.

The problem, though, is that `pip freeze` still lists the packages, even though they've been explicitly uninstalled through `pip`.

As an example, both `pip freeze | grep pylint` and `pacman -Qqe | grep pylint` indicate that the package is installed. I can successfully uninstall the package through either `sudo pacman -Rs python-pylint` or through `sudo pip uninstall pylint`.

If I do so - uninstall the package **either through `pip` or through `pacman`** - the package disappears from `pip freeze`'s list, and `pacman -Qqe` no longer finds anything. If I then reinstall the package through `pacman -S`, the package then reappears in `pip freeze`. Reinstalling the package through `pip` does not prompt it to reappear in `pacman -Qqe`.

Uninstalling a package from `pip` by running `sudo pip uninstall packagename`, then reinstalling it with the `--user` flag (i.e. `pip install --user packagename`) causes `sudo pip freeze` not to display the package, but `pip freeze` to continue to display it. Reinstalling the package through `pacman` causes it to reappear on both lists.

---

I do not believe this question to be a duplicate of the one [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640530/pip-freeze-lists-uninstalled-packages); in that question, the user was unable to remove packages from `pip freeze` by uninstalling them and the problem was tracked to multiple different `pip` binaries.

In this case, uninstalling a package through `pip` does remove it from `pip freeze`, and `which pip` and `sudo which pip` have the same output: `/usr/bin/pip`. Additionally, `sudo pip freeze` and `pip freeze` produce the same output.

However, the test proposed by the accepted answer to the question linked above exhibits what I believe to be strange behavior. (At the time of running the below test, `pylint` had been uninstalled from `pip` and reinstalled through `pacman`.)

```
$ python -c 'import pkg_name' &> /dev/null && echo installed || echo not installed
Using config file /home/[my user name]/.pylintrc
not installed
```

The package is indeed installed - not only does it print the config file line, but I can use the package as normal (`pylint foo.py`). Wouldn't I then expect the test to print `installed`?

---

To get to my actual questions about this issue:

- What can I do to ascertain which packages are actually installed only through `pip`, and which are "installed" through both `pip` and `pacman`?
- What can be done to correct the broader problem: `pip` tracking packages installed through `pacman`?

Comment: 1. can you verify your `pip` serves the same Python installation that you access via `python -c`? Run `pip -V`, it should print you the installation directory. It should match the directory returned by `python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"`.

Comment: @hoefling Yes, it looks like it.

`$ pip -V`
`pip 10.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

`$ python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"`
`['/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`

Comment: 2. it is not necessary that the distribution name (as in `pip install NAME`) matches the root package name (as in `python -c "import NAME"`). While this is true for many distributions, there are lots of discrepant ones, for example `scikit-learn` install codebase in `sklearn` package, or `wxPython` installing codebase in `wx`.

Comment: @hoefling Yeah, that's a good point. I was hung up more on the issue described in the question (I broke off the process to investigate this issue), but I'll re-evaluate and check packages again with other options if I can't find them via the naive package name in the Arch repositories.

Comment: 3. I'm not aware about how `pacman` works, but I would start with restricting the `pip list` only to the packages that are not a dependency of other packages (leafs in the dependency tree). These a likely to be either installed via `pip install`, or via `pacman`. Unfortunetly, `pip` itself can't build a dependency tree, but `pipdeptree` can - install it as user (so you know later that you didn't install it via `pacman`) with `pip install --user pipdeptree`, then run `pipdeptree | grep -v '^ '`. This way, you should have a lot less packages to analyze, rest are just dependencies.

Comment: @hoefling I've just now noticed that if I install a package with `pip install --user packagename`, `pip freeze` reports the package installed, while `sudo pip freeze` does not. Unfortunately, I don't think this can be a solution to the problem since reinstalling the package through pacman prompts it to reappear both in `pip freeze` and `sudo pip freeze`, but it at least adds new information. I'll update the post with this. To the subject of your comment: good idea, I'll do that.

Comment: No, I don't mean this to be the solution, just a temporary install of `pipdeptree` to help you sort the packages into explicitly installed ones and dependencies (which are not interesting per se). You can safely remove `pipdeptree` once you obtained the dependency tree. However, I usually install python packages via `pip install --user` when my system's package manager doesn't have that package, I can then easily filter packages installed via `pip` by issuing `pip list --user`.

Comment: @hoefling No, I understand - I didn't take that to be a solution. I just wanted to share a new piece of information I found in the process of using `pipdeptree` (which appears to be extremely useful for this - thank you for pointing me to this tool!). Once I've migrated all available packages from `pip` to `pacman`, I'll uninstall/reinstall the remaining packages (those requiring `pip`) with the `--user` flag - this seems to be the best practice to avoid issues like mine in the first place, for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a python script ([gist link](https://gist.github.com/hoefling/314565368a66c308b4d7d407a3028cb7)) that checks all python packages whether they were installed with `pacman`.

#### installation

Download the script and make it executable:

```
$ wget https://gist.github.com/hoefling/314565368a66c308b4d7d407a3028cb7/raw/7b81553fa0a84b92a90fbaa0746482d0ec18516c/pip-query -O pip-query
$ chmod +x pip-query
```

#### usage

Here's an example calling it in a `base/archlinux` docker container where I have installed `python-pip` and `python-wheel`:

```
$ ./pip-query
Package    Version Owner
---------- ------- -----------------
appdirs    1.4.3   python-appdirs
packaging  17.1    python-packaging
pip        9.0.1   python-pip
pyparsing  2.2.0   python-pyparsing
setuptools 39.2.0  python-setuptools
six        1.11.0  python-six
wheel      0.31.1  python-wheel
```

The output resembles the output of `pip list --format=columns`, but with an additional column `Owner` that prints the name of the system package that owns the python package.

Let's test with a package installed directly with `pip`:

```
$ sudo pip install tqdm
...
$ ./pip-query
Package    Version Owner
---------- ------- -----------------
appdirs    1.4.3   python-appdirs
packaging  17.1    python-packaging
pip        9.0.1   python-pip
pyparsing  2.2.0   python-pyparsing
setuptools 39.2.0  python-setuptools
six        1.11.0  python-six
tqdm       4.23.4
wheel      0.31.1  python-wheel
```

The `Owner` column has an empty cell in `tqdm` row, this indicates `tqdm` was not installed by `pacman`. Uninstall `tqdm` with `pip`:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall -y tqdm
```

and install it with `pacman`:

```
$ pacman -S python-tqdm
```

#### permanent installation

If you want, place `pip-query` file somewhere in your `PATH`, preferably something local like `$HOME/.local/bin` to call it like a proper executable with

```
$ pip-query
```

#### adapting for other package managers

It should be pretty easy to adapt the script for using with other package managers if you want to. For example, if I change `['pacman', '-Qqo', file]` to `['qfile', '-q', file]`, the script will work on Gentoo without any further modification*. If your package manager doesn't support pure package name printing, extract the relevant info from the `out` string with regex or whatever.

#### batch reinstalling packages with `pacman`

You can modify `pip-query`, or follow the Unix philosophy and write some bash command that does reinstalling for you. However, you have to deal with multiple suggestions made by `pacman` (as in the example below) and implement the case when nothing was suggested. Here is my humble attempt (not an expert in bash):

```bash
$ ./pip-query | tail -n +3 | while read line ; do split=(${line}); \
> if [ "${#split[@]}" -eq "2" ]; then pkgname=${split[0]}; \
> echo -e "Suggestion: pip uninstall -y $pkgname && pacman -S $(pacman -Sspq $pkgname | tr '\n' ' ')"; \
> fi; done
Suggestion: pip uninstall -y tqdm && pacman -S python-tqdm python2-tqdm
```

Enhance this and you have an automated solution for reinstall task.

---

<sub>*: assuming `app-portage/portage-utils` is emerged.</sub>